# Python zipfile module adds files with null bytes instead of correct content

Tags: python, zip

When I use `zipfile.ZipFile.writestr`, the file contains the correct amount of characters afterwards, but all of them are null bytes.

Minimal example:

```
import zipfile
z=zipfile.ZipFile("test.zip", "w")
z.writestr("foo", "test")
z.close()
```

The resulting test.zip has a file "foo" inside, which contains 4 null bytes.

Comment: That works OK for me.

Comment: Indeed. It is "ark" (kde archive program), which cannot open or extract it correctly. "unzip" on the commandline and file-roller work just fine. On the other hand, ark handles other zipfiles with textfiles inside without any problem.

Answer (score 1):

Got the same problem, and it seems ZipInfo is the obvious workaround.

```
import zipfile, os

name = 'foo.txt'
data = b'This is a test text.'

open(name, 'wb').write(data)
zipfile.ZipFile('write.zip', 'w').write(name)              # OK for Ark
zipfile.ZipFile('writestr.zip', 'w').writestr(name, data)  # nulls by Ark

wrt_attr = zipfile.ZipFile('write.zip').getinfo(name)
wrts_attr = zipfile.ZipFile('writestr.zip').getinfo(name)

os.remove(name)
os.remove('write.zip')
os.remove('writestr.zip')

for attr in wrt_attr.__slots__:
    if getattr(wrt_attr, attr) != getattr(wrts_attr, attr):
        attr, getattr(wrt_attr, attr), getattr(wrts_attr, attr)

attr = 'external_attr'
oct(getattr(wrt_attr, attr)>>16), oct(getattr(wrts_attr, attr)>>16)
```

The [ZIP spec](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT) says, `external_attr` should be set to zero if the content is came from `stdin`. However, `writestr` constructs an [invalid](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.0/Lib/zipfile.py#1096) external_attr when the first argument is str.

It could be

```
0o100xxx (regular file with umasked permission)
```

or

```
zero (as the spec)
```

but not

```
0oxxx (file type absent)
```

Comment: So is this a python (zipfile module) bug? And why does input from writestr need another handling than a normal file? Has it some attribute, that data can be appended, which doesn't work when its included as "file", or what is the reasoning there? Just curious about it. And at line 1096 ``zinfo.external_attr = 0o600 << 16`` looks like somebody has an idea, what he's doing, but sadly he did not document why it's that way.

Answer (score 0):

Seems not to be a python problem, as its only "ark", which cannot open this file.
On the other hand, it seems to be encoded in some way, that ark cannot read it (while other unzip programs can).

Comment: accepting it, as ark has the problem, not the general zipfile. If somebody knows, what actually causes this and how to build zips which are handled correctly by all archive programs, i will accept your answer.

Comment: removed the accepted attribute again, as it seems unclear if ark or zipfile is the problem.